# "What need is there to ..." vs "Is there a need to ..."

Tags: grammaticality, nuance

Is a question that starts with "What need is there to" grammatically correct?

For example:

> What need is there to tell a lie just to make a joke?

If so, is there a difference in meaning or nuance between that clause and "Is there a need to"?

> What need is there to tell a lie just to make a joke?
>
> Is there a need to tell a lie just to make a joke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What need is there to tell a lie just to make a joke?

I would choose this question if I want the responder to respond with the very detail of the answer. This is not a suitable choice if you do not need to know *why* somebody is telling a lie just to make a joke.

> Is there a need to tell a lie just to make a joke?

This is, in my honestest opinion, a “boolean” question: It can not be answered with detail unless the responder chooses to.

**Edit:** I would like to add that these may be rhetorical as well, as pointed out by others. Alternative rhetorical statements are:

- Why are you telling a lie just to make a joke?
- You shouldn't have told a lie just to make a joke.

These can be used to emphasize that the second person is very, very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a need?*: answer yes or no.

*What need is there?*: an elaborate answer is expected or the question is rhetorical

to make the first sentence in your example rhetorical, I would expect a *really*

*Is there really a need to tell a lie here?*

but the example sentences do not roll off my tongue in any case... They do not sound natural

I would say

Was it really necessary to lie just for the fun of it?

Comment: Are you sure the first form can't be rhetorical as well?

Comment: Not to my ears. - then you would need something like really... Is there really a need to...